# fullcalendar not showing event base on event time

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am building a event calendar within Hero Framework. I have got my fullcalendar linked to DB via JSON method. The record is showing start at "2012-04-18 12:00" and end at "2012-04-18 14:00" but calendar failed to show the event base on the time. It is shown as ALL-DAY event. Any idea how to solve that?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        firstHour: 9,
        select: function(start, end) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    },
                    false // make the event "stick"
                );

                var startDateString = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm');
                var endDateString = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{url}ajaxpost/add',
                    data: {
                        startDate: startDateString,
                        endDate: endDateString,
                        eventTitle: title                            
                    },
                    dateType: 'json',
                    success: function (resp) {
                        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

                    }
                });
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        editable: true,
        events: "{url}ajaxget/data",
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to set the event allDay property to false

Answer (score 1):

When you return the events from your `{url}ajaxget/data` url, you need to specify that the event is not all day.

You do this my setting an `allDay` field on each `event` that is not all day long.

It may look like this:

```
[{
    start : 10000000,
    end :   10000500,
    title : 'example event'
    allDay : false
}, ... ]
```

You can also find this info in [the documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/).

Comment: thanks for the documentation link it resolve my issue